# Supply desgin for two TDA2003 amplifiers and TL072 stereo operational amplifier

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, split

I made two TDA2003 amplifers, one for each channel to act as stereo device. For preamplifier I want to use TL072 stereo opamp, but supply od +12 and -12 for IC is giving me a problem. How can I make +-12 split supply for TL072 from toroid transformer that has two 18V secondary windings. On each winding is LM317 regulator limiting voltage to 18V.

Comment: Which AC transformer are you using? Can you link a datasheet?

Comment: I'm using Talema toroidal transformer prim: 230V, sec:2x18V, 120VA

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get split power from an AC transformer with dual secondary windings, using only positive regulators;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjUSXb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It could just as easily use adjustable regulators.